# ToolTip on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show a tooltip onClick (Instead of hover) and it should fade out after 200ms

Any help ?

Comment: ...any *progress*? Where are you stuck?

Comment: if you're talking about default tooltip that uses `title` attribute then it's not possible, you will need to write your own javascript/jquery library or use ready solutions like qTip or something else (just search for them online, there are plenty)

Comment: I'm new to javascript and jQuery ...And I have been searching for a while now for a library that could show a tooltip on button click and then fade out after 200ms

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest the Twitter Bootstrap library - It has all that you want, and has been implemented very neatly
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this jQuery-plugin:

[TipTip jQuery Plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin)

Here is an example HTML code:

```
<img class="example" src="example.jpg" title="Example text" />
```

You can customize the tooltip like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".example").tipTip({activation: "click"});
});
```

The tooltip will appear when you click on the image, but it will disappear only when you mouse out the image.